# C# application stopped working

Tags: c#, windows-vista

I made a C# windows application in visual c# express 2008. I executed the exe file seperately on my PC and it worked perfectly.. Now when I ran the same file on another computer having vista an error occurred "WindowsFormapplication has stopped working". On my computer too it stops working after 5-10 min. So is the problem with my code or is it anything else?

I am a newbie here... Any help would be appreciated..

Edited.....

It uses timers:

```
System.Timers.Timer timer = new System.Timers.Timer();
timer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(startup.onTimerEvent);
timer.AutoReset = true;
timer.Interval = 60000;
timer.Start();
Application.Run();
GC.KeepAlive(timer);
```

It also creates and sets a registry key..

Comment: Some details about what the app does would help us help you.  Does it do something that requires administrator access?

Comment: We're gonna need more information... a stack trace perhaps? maybe even some source code?

Comment: I'm guessing an exception is thrown and not handled by your application. When the exception gets to the top of the stack the operating system catches it and brings up the "XXX has stopped working" dialog. So, we just need to know what that exeption is and where it is being thrown from.

Comment: What part of the registry does it write to?

Comment: You may want to check the Application EventLog for info about any unhandled exceptions that are being thrown by your app.

Comment: @Troggy it gets set as a windows startup application

Comment: @Sahil No, he meant what is the registry key that you are writing to.

Comment: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run I think thats what you want.. the key to make an application run on startup

Comment: Try running it in debug mode on both machines, see what exceptions being thrown and what line of code it is being thrown on, then you will have more information with regards to hunting down the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing it is a permissions issue. On Vista the system is locked down tighter so if your program couldn't get the permission it needed it will throw an exception. If that happens at the start of the program that's why you get the error on start up.

On your own machine you may be waiting 5-10 minutes because it is a different bug that is causing the application to fail.

Comment: Just to add now you've mentioned HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE - This requires admin rights. If you don't have them an exception will be thrown. On Vista even if you are logged on as admin you need to elevate your privileges to run as Admin.

Answer (score 0):

Could you be using something from a version of .NET that is not available on the second machine?

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Colin. Sounds like it is no doubt a permission issue when your application is trying to create the Registry Key.

You should have a wrapper which checks the user has permissions before attempting to write, or at least handles if the user does not...