# Published application cannot start, but release/debug version starts well

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, publishing, oneclick

I have a problem when I try to Run published Application. When I Run Release or Debug Version from VS (key F5) everything work well. So I try to publish my application (no problem). After this I Installed application by oneClick installer. Instalation was finished without problem, but when I try to run this installed application, I only see message: Program has Stop Working.

Please, does anybody know where should be a problem? It´s really wierd, I suppose, when the application run correctly from VS, then it Should run after installing to!? Or am I wrong?
Or is there some option to reset *Publish* settings in Visual Studio?

Thanks a lot!!!

Comment: maybe this one help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1129883/c-sharp-application-stopped-working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends how you have ClickOnce setup, but the main reason this happens is the ClickOnce system encounters an error while checking for updates or running the `.application` from the remote location.

It should give you the option to see a log of the problem (or at least the nasty temp file it threw it in).

From here you can determine the problem ClickOnce is having.

Most Common Problems I would Suspect:

- The User's having trouble communicating thier auth token / credentials to the web server the ClickOnce app is on.
- There's another web-related issue downloading the app manifest or `.application` from the server
- Group / Local Policy Problems
- Broken install in on local machine's ClickOnce somewhere causing it to have problems overwriting on disk or finding an appropriate location to setup the clickonce package.
- Broken install in on local machine's ClickOnce causing a GUID Conflict (I.e. your app and the broken install can't be upgraded, but share the same GUID)
- Antivirus / Firewall blocking access to the web component from the executable clickonce deploy.

These are all the problems I've encountered with ClickOnce and the reasons we've primarily moved away from it to a Wix style installer.